# How do I draw the following graph in tikz-pgf?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

The tikz-pgf source code

```
\[\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{1.5} \def\b{2}
\path
(-\a,0) node (A) {$A$}      
(\a,0) node (B) {$B$}
(0,-\b) node[align=center] (C) {$C$};
\begin{scope}[nodes={midway,scale=.75}]
\draw[<-] (A)--(C.120) node[left]{some text};
\draw[->] (C.60)--(B) node[right]{some text};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\]
```

produces the following diagram:

[image]

My questions:

(1) How do I turn the text "some text" on the arrows along the direction of the arrow instead of the horizontal position as it is currently? That is, I want to text "some text" transversally or parallel to the arrows' direction.

(2) How to increase the arrow-head size ?

Comment: take a look in `pgfmanual` p.47 `sloped` and the `arrows.meta` library section 16.5

Comment: BTW, why do you put the tikzpicture into math mode? That‘s not needed. //. BTW, your code as posted can never compile when copied …

Comment: @MS-SPO, i didn't understand. The code i wrote, compiling without any error. Can you write other code doing my job ?

Comment: @learner, please compare the parts before \begin{tikzpicture} and its end e.g. in the answer Zarko gave. // Are you using some special Latex tool?

Comment: @learner. below I illustrated what I mean ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

By use of the  Ti*k*Z libraries and defining of the picture elements styles:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 15mm and 20mm,
       every edge/.style = {draw, -Straight Barb},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt, sloped}
                        ]
\node (A) {$A$};
\node (C) [below right=of A] {$C$};
\node (B) [above right=of C] {$B$};
%
\draw   (C) edge ["some text"]  (A)
        (C) edge ["some text"]  (B);
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: @CarLaTeX, thank you very much! This is not hard to correct . Done!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However the command `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,quotes}`  shows errors "I can not find tikzlibraryarrows.meta......."

Comment: @learner, than you have very ancient version of `tikz` package. Upgrade your installation. Temporary version is 3.1.10.

Comment: @Zarko, I think so. But can you suggest how to increase the size of the "head of the arrow" in my above code ?

Comment: @learner, you can omit to use `arrows.meta`  library and instead of `Straight Barb` use simple `>`. But I would first upgrade your LaTeX installation.

Answer (score 3):

This answer has two parts:

- a solution
- some hints for writing better questions

**For the solution:**

- use tikz library `arrows.meta`
- avoid the scope and scaling, as a different font size seems to be what you want for the labels
- the need for TeX's `\def` isn't really clear to me; I suggest to use `\pic` instead
- for the labels, the node was placed after the next nodes coordinate, e.g. `(A)` ... which is probably not what you want
- for cleaner code it's always a good idea to refactor, here into some style definitions at the beginning (`lbl` etc.)

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% <<< new

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[% <<< new
        lbl/.style={sloped,below,% <<< as requested
            font={\scriptsize}},% <<< fontsize, instead of scaling
        >=Stealth% <<< arrow tip from arrows.meta
    ]
        \def\a{1.5} \def\b{2}% <<< shouldn't be used here; what's the need?
        \path
        (-\a,  0) node (A) {$A$}      
        ( \a,  0) node (B) {$B$}
        (  0,-\b) node (C) {$C$};
        
        % ~~~ not needed, not really what you intend ~~~~~~~~~~~
%       (0,-\b) node[align=center] (C) {$C$};% <<< only useful for\\multi-\\line
%       \begin{scope}[nodes={midway,scale=.75}]% <<< not needed
%           \draw[<-] (A)--(C.120) node[left]{some text};
%           \draw[->] (C.60)--(B) node[right]{some text};

        % ~~~ alternative ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            \draw[->] (C.120)-- node[left ,lbl]{some text} (A);
            \draw[->] (C.60) -- node[right,lbl]{some text} (B);
%       \end{scope}% <<< not needed, related to labels font size
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

---

**Hints for writing better questions**

To assist your learning, both wrt. Latex and this site, the images below is what you'll get from a compile on a regular Latex-System, when copying your code-snippet. Turns out, it's incomplete ... (and faulty anyway)

So this answer shows the process to turn a boiled-down code snippet (which is good) into a MWE, people can copy, try and improve right away. I.e. posting the last code shown here is a nice MWE.

BTW, here is a [good compilation of how to write MWE's](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), both within the answers and links in the many comments.

###### 0. From the comments

It looks like the Latex-environment used here, `TexStudio`, allows to write less code. This is probably due to this tools autocompletion feature, see the [wiki](http://transit.iut2.upmf-grenoble.fr/doc/texstudio/html/usermanual_en.html#SECTION040) and some [.clw files](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/hg/ci/default/tree/completion/) .

However, there are many ways to run Latex, ranging from command lines, via IDE's, via online, using Docker to whatHaveYou. So to enable your audience here to copy, compile and work on your code right away for answers, this `basic structure` should always be present `in code you post`:

```
\documentclass ...% insert yours

% ~~~ preamble ~~~
\usepackage ... %  insert yours, the RELEVANT ones only
...

\begin{document}
   % your relevant code here
\end{document}
```

###### 1. Compile errors

Ok, this seems to work in your environment, BUT ...

```
\[\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{1.5} \def\b{2}
\path
(-\a,0) node (A) {$A$}      
(\a,0) node (B) {$B$}
(0,-\b) node[align=center] (C) {$C$};
\begin{scope}[nodes={midway,scale=.75}]
\draw[<-] (A)--(C.120) node[left]{some text};
\draw[->] (C.60)--(B) node[right]{some text};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\]
```

... it can't compile for most users here on a regular Latex-system, which is (invisible, via F1) `pdflatex` here:

[image: err1]

###### 2. Let's add the document-environment

```
\begin{document}
    \[\begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\a{1.5} \def\b{2}
        \path
        (-\a,0) node (A) {$A$}      
        (\a,0) node (B) {$B$}
        (0,-\b) node[align=center] (C) {$C$};
        \begin{scope}[nodes={midway,scale=.75}]
            \draw[<-] (A)--(C.120) node[left]{some text};
            \draw[->] (C.60)--(B) node[right]{some text};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \] 
\end{document}
```

Still complaining: doesn't know what a `tikzpicture` should be:

[image: err2]

###### 3. Enable compiling a Tikz-document

So you need to specify a documentclass, and use the tikz-package. This one

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
```

is the same as stating

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \[\begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\a{1.5} \def\b{2}
        \path
        (-\a,0) node (A) {$A$}      
        (\a,0) node (B) {$B$}
        (0,-\b) node[align=center] (C) {$C$};
        \begin{scope}[nodes={midway,scale=.75}]
            \draw[<-] (A)--(C.120) node[left]{some text};
            \draw[->] (C.60)--(B) node[right]{some text};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \] 
\end{document}
```

But it still complaints, this time about the math-mode you wanted:

[image: err3]

###### 4. So let's remove the math-mode

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\a{1.5} \def\b{2}
        \path
        (-\a,0) node (A) {$A$}      
        (\a,0) node (B) {$B$}
        (0,-\b) node[align=center] (C) {$C$};
        \begin{scope}[nodes={midway,scale=.75}]
            \draw[<-] (A)--(C.120) node[left]{some text};
            \draw[->] (C.60)--(B) node[right]{some text};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

YIPPEEH! Compiles for the first time. ONLY NOW we can turn to the `tikz` code itself and rework it ...

[image: compiled]

###### 5. Hope you get it

THIS is the kind of rework, which often can only be pure guessing about posters preamble, such incomplete code snippets imposes on this community.

Guess, how it impacts

- number of replies
- quality of replies
- speed of replies

Learn to do better, please.

Comment: True, and meant that way.

Comment: Ok, true again. So I will rework it into a QA later, as a kind of example or procedure, and delete or disable it here.

Comment: @MS-SPO, I understand. Thanks for the effort. But fortunately my "Tex Studio" editor smoothly complied my code.

Comment: Ok. So we all will continue wasting a lot of time on this subject only ... before even touching your questions ... Do you think that's the best approach here? // Ok, I'm discussing. Will stop here. Bye

Comment: @CarLaTeX, just added a solution part.

Answer (score 2):

Your problems are quickly solved using `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzcdset{
    arrow style=tikz,
    arrows={>={To[width=.4cm, length=.15cm]}}
    }

\begin{document}
Text is parallel to the arrow:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
    A&&B\\[24pt]
    &C\ar[ul, sloped, swap, "\text{some text}"]\ar[ur, sloped, swap, "\text{some text}"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
Text crosses the arrow:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
    A&&B\\[24pt]
    &C\ar[ul, "\text{some text}" description]\ar[ur, "\text{some text}" description]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

I used "To" in the arrow setting:

```
arrow style=tikz,
arrows={>={To[width=.4cm, length=.15cm]}}
```

but you can use any style provided by TikZ, with any width and length you prefer.

[image]